# Android in-app billing example with black waiting screen

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I see a bunch of threads here for android in-app billing, I went through them but can't find solution to my problem:

I'm trying to run the in-app-billing-v03, i.e. the TrivialDrive app. I have followed exactly what is written in the README file until I signed the apk and installed it with adb onto my test device. Then I ran it but what I see is a black screen with "ONE SEC" in the middle and nothing else. I have absolutely no idea what's going on behind since I can't run it with debug.

so had anyone the same experience and would love to share a solution? the sample's not providing any information.

Comment: Why can't you use logcat to see what's happening/

Comment: thanks for commenting. I can't run it from eclipse, could you tell me how I can view logcat when I ran the app from device directly? I'm a newbie to android.

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Other -> LogCat from Eclipse upper menu.

Comment: It shows nothing there. only when I click the back button it throws a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have 50 reputation so I can't leave a comment...

I have the same problem, and can describe in a little bit more detail what is happening.

In the IABHelper.startSetup() call, it never triggers the onIabSetupFinished() callback.

In the startSetup() method this call

```
        mContext.bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                         mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

returns false and never calls mServiceConn.onServiceConnected (which is where the onIabSetupFinished() is called).

Logcat says something like: EDIT: When I went to run to check this logcat statement, it started working. It WAS saying something

```
"com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND not resolved"
```

What did I do to fix this? No idea, but I'm guessing it has something to do with that IInAppBillingService generated file. Check your build path to make sure /gen is included in the output and do a clean/build. You can debug this particular problem with a debug signature in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add an answer that I think is the real solution to the problem.

Did you do a factory reset of your device to get it properly setup with your test account? If so, open Google Play. I noticed that my problem went away after I opened Google Play for the first time. It will add "Google Play Store" and "Google Play services" to your downloaded apps. (Go to settings->apps) After I did this it started working. Android does automatic lazy downloading apparently. I have a native android OS (Samsung Galaxy Nexus) running 4.1.1.

EDIT: To test if users have Google Play setup properly check this link.

[In-App Billing v3, bindService() Intent can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933632/in-app-billing-v3-bindservice-intent-cant-be-found)