# In-App Billing v3, bindService() Intent can't be found

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using in-app billing from Google for Android for the first time. However, if a user doesn't have an internet connection or no google framework installed (e.g. with custom roms) and probably other occasions  (like wrong/old market version etc.)
This method (inside the provided IabHelper class):

```
        mContext.bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                         mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Doesn't work and no service get's established. With a small debugging information from "Activity Manager":

```
12-17 19:58:31.184: W/ActivityManager(76): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND }: not found
```

Has anyone found any way to "catch" this error in a meaningful way, or any workaround to check if the Intent/Package is available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

argh, found answer myself shortly after:

You have to check if the intent receiver is available by implementing a method like suggested here: 
[can i use this intent - blogpost][1]

(edit) However, this method needs some serious changes to be applicable for the billing-service, as the original method only checks for default intents, which is not what we want.

however, my implementation looks like the following and seems to work, at least on those devices, specifications etc. i tested: (ONLY TESTED FOR V3 OF IN APP BILLING)

```
public static boolean isBillingAvailable(Context context) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentServices(intent, 0);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey , i am trying to implement In-app billing version3. Started reading documenting but did not get any library project in my sdk to start it . Please help if you can in implementing this new version of In-app billing. My email id(avi.it.128@gmail.com) for if you can send some codes or library project to read. Thanks :)

Comment: still a question: On a familiy member's device, it says that billing isn't available there too. it's android 4.0 htc sensation with palystore etc. any ideas?

Comment: No idea, usually i am ready to help but this tym  i need help from you :(

Comment: ok, tested it. THIS DOES NOT NECESSERALY WORK! it seems i have overlooked something. will digg into that deeper...
@Kabir121 : you have an email

Comment: FINALLY: solution is here, needed to make some changes, fuh.. this method should be included in IabHelper or something...

Comment: Hey, Thanks for help :) . Almost implemented, just have a single confusion or can say did not understood from google's link that how to restore transaction. If every product can not be purchased again an again then how to to get info that i have already purchased the product. thanks.. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21365/discussion-between-kabir121-and-aeefire)

Comment: Did you get in app billing working on the 4.0 device? I'm implementing billing and it works perfectly on newer APIs, but it fails at the bindService call.

Comment: I implemented it on for API lvl 9+. Works everywhere, where the new playstore has been pushed to.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to distinguish between a bindService() to InAppBillingService that fails because of some transient problem (e.g., the service has crashed), and a bindService() that fails because there IS no installed manifest with an intent-filter indicating support for InAppBillingService (which would mean that there is no real hope of ever attaining such support on that device).  Is that correct?

I'd be curious to know just what you do when in-app billing is transiently unavailable, that you would do differently if it were entirely missing from the device.  TIA.

Comment: This basically does the second thing you said. It checks if the right service (e.g. right playstore version with this service) is available. So it checks if a "Manifest" with this Service is registered.

Comment: Looks like the latest version of the IABHelper implements this check

Comment: you don't need to implement your own check methods, `bindService` returns a boolean value and if it returns false then something went wrong (e.g., when Emulator doesn't have Google Play Services)