# InAppBillingService fails to bind

Tags: android

I'm doing basic in app billing and the service fails to bind.

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

IInAppBillingService mservice;
ServiceConnection connection;
String inappid = "android.test.purchased"; // replace this with your in-app
                                            // product id

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mservice = null;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mservice = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };
    getApplicationContext()
            .bindService(
                    new Intent(
                            "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                    connection, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Button purchaseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purchase);
    purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
            skuList.add(inappid);
            Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
            querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
            Bundle skuDetails;
            try {
                skuDetails = mservice.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                        "inapp", querySkus);

                int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (response == 0) {

                    ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
                            .getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                    for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                        String sku = object.getString("productId");
                        String price = object.getString("price");
                        if (sku.equals(inappid)) {
                            System.out.println("price " + price);
                            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mservice
                                    .getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku,
                                            "inapp",
                                            "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                                    .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                            startIntentSenderForResult(
                                    pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                                    new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                    Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString(inappid);
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "You have bought the " + sku
                                + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (connection != null) {
        unbindService(connection);
    }
}
```

}

When I run the app, the bindService method returns false and mService is null. The log also gives me this message:

```
Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517 com.raico.coinage.MainActivity.onCreate:51 android.app.Activity.performCreate:5231
```

Comment: Can you check if the intent receiver is available by implementing isBillingAvailable(). Check the examples http://stackoverflow.com/a/13933785/1237175

Comment: I implemented the method and even when billing is available, I still have the same issue.

Comment: The warning is a known issue. See [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/29/dealing-deprecations-bindservice.html). However, unless you're running on an API level 20 device or emulator, it doesn't explain the failure to bind.

Answer (score 3):

Change your MainActivity.onCreate() to call  getApplicationContext().bindService() similarly to this:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
getApplicationContext().bindService(serviceIntent, connection, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This will make the intent explicit which is safer and should work on Lollipop too.